# Magento2: crontab not working in magento for emarsys catalog generation?

Tags: magento2, admin, cron, crontab

I am trying to run the command `php bin/module cron:run` but getting error in `CLI`.
Here is my `crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
        <group id="default">
            <job name="emarsys_catalog_bulk_export" instance="Emarsys\Emarsys\Cron\ProductBulkExport" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 0 30 2 3</schedule>
            </job>
        </group>
     </config>
```

**ERROR :**

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Invalid Document
  Element 'job': The attribute 'instance' is required but missing.
  Line: 4

 Element 'job': The attribute 'method' is required but missing.
  Line: 4

 Element 'schedule': Element content is not allowed, because the type definition is simple.
  Line: 5

 Element 'schedule': [facet 'minLength'] The value has a length of '0'; this underruns the allowed minimum length of '5'.
  Line: 5

  Element 'schedule': '' is not a valid value of the list type 'scheduleDeclaration'.
  Line: 5

 Element 'run': This element is not expected. Expected is ( config_path ).
  Line: 8


cron:run [--group GROUP] [--bootstrap BOOTSTRAP]
```

Comment: I don't think XML code has the issue.

Comment: Can u tell me what is the issue?

Comment: use `*` instedad of `0` in `<schedule>` in crontab xml

Comment: @IdhamChoudry i tried * instead of 0 still same error

Comment: @Parthavi try to put `instance` first then `name` in <job> tag

Answer (score 0):

For the above error check if in any chrontab.xml file u have not use instance and method as attribute

Answer (score 0):

**I Think XML Code has the Issue :-**

> **crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="Emarsys\Emarsys\Cron\ProductBulkExport" method="execute" name="emarsys_catalog_bulk_export">
            <schedule>0 0 30 2 3</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**Try this**